# internal error, the table won't show anything

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

i was trying to do a verification first on the emp_id before it do a query of showing the tbl_leave table

but unfortunately, python always give me

> raise InternalError("Unread result found")
> mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
> File "c:\Users\Booster\Documents\python\main.py", line 230, in showtimeout
> if con.is_connected():
> File "C:\Users\Booster\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 322, in is_connected
> self.handle_unread_result()

to the terminal

and here is the code block of it:

```
def showtimeout():
    timerec = tkinter.Tk()
    timerec.title("Time in Records")
    timerec.geometry("600x200")
    try:
        con = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', port='3306', database='db_empdb', user='root', password='')
        tree=ttk.Treeview(timerec)
        cursor = con.cursor()

        query = "SELECT emp_id FROM tbl_employee WHERE emp_id = %s"
        cursor.execute(query, (adwin_entry.get(),))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result:
            query = f"SELECT * FROM tbl_timeout WHERE emp_id = {adwin_entry.get()}"
            cursor.execute(query)
            con.commit()
            rows=cursor.fetchall()
            columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
            tree["columns"] = columns
            tree.heading("#0", text="Index")
            for col in columns:
                tree.heading(col, text=col)
                tree.column(col, width=100, anchor="center")
            for i, row in enumerate(rows):
                tree.insert("", "end", text=str(i), values=row)
            tree.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
            con.commit()
            cursor.close()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Failed", "Employee ID not found!")
            
    except Error as err:
        print("Access Failed! {}".format(err))
    finally:
        if con.is_connected():
            con.close()
            print("Connection Successful!")
```

i was trying to verify the emp_id first and if it's correct, it will show the records of that emp_id inside the tbl_timeout

Comment: In this line you forgot to add the parameter probably:
```query = "SELECT emp_id FROM tbl_employee WHERE emp_id = %s" ```
It should be like: ```query = "SELECT emp_id FROM tbl_employee WHERE emp_id = %s" %emp_id ```
 . Where ```%emp_id``` should be defined above.

Comment: No @MuhammadWaqarAnwar, that is called a prepared statement and it is OK

Comment: I don´t understand why your first query uses prepared statements and the second one uses f strings. You shouldn´t use f string. Also, why are you doing a commit?? It is not useful after a SELECT